# Remove DRM Protection

Tags: drm, video-conversion

I recently purchased a documentary video from Amazon ([Link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001EOE6EW))

I cannot play the video because it's restricted for visitors from inside USA. But I'm not in USA and so I cannot play it.

I found this [article](http://undrm.info/remove-DRM-protection/) about removing DRM but neither ways is not working for me. Because while I have purchased the video LEGALLY but I cannot Acquire License because my IP is out of USA. Unfortunately I have not access to USA VPN and VPN is not a choice for me.

Is there a way to remove DRM Protection without Acquiring license or recording it?

Comment: You might not have a US VPN, but what about routing the data through a US-based proxy server? If you can't do that, just ask Amazon to undo the purchase and refund your money, then source the documentary some other way.

Comment: Please close this question. Its basically asking the community to help someone circumvent DRM.

Comment: @deltaray - circumventing drm is not always illegal or unethical.  Depending on the OP's country of origin, if the local law permits and the documentary is not otherwise available, this might be a perfectly moral thing to do.

Comment: @Joel-Coehoorn It doesn't matter whether it is moral or not. Morals are up to you.  But its illegal because circumventing a company's DRM violates the DMCA. By giving him a solution you are potentially implicating yourself and Stack Exchange. That's why I care. Not because its unethical, but because I don't want people here to get in trouble.

Comment: @deltaray - It's not ILLEGAL or UNETHICAL. I purchased the video and I have right to watch it. But it did not allow to watch the video because I'm not inside USA. Is this ethical? I really need to watch this documentary for a scholar article I'm writing, I pay for it but and I downloaded the video (1 GB) But I cannot play it because I'm not USA resident.

Comment: @deltaray - Actually I think there is no solution for this problem. I cannot play video and AFAK nobody actually break DRM, yet. I think my case is a good example that everybody should ban DRM content. I pay for the video and download it (It take 2 days because my connection is slow) But I cannot play it, only because I'm not USA resident. Is this fair?

Comment: @Mani, I'm sympathetic with your problem, but I think the solution is for you to contact Amazon about a solution or getting your money back. Its not fair to you if they allowed you to buy something that you can't play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [UltraVPN](http://www.ultravpn.fr/) (cross-platform) or [FreeVPN](http://thefreevpn.com/) (Windows only).  The second  one changes your browser homepage.

Comment: Neither UltraVPN and FreeVPN are not USA VPN. I think I have to buy a USA VPN and change my Internet Provider. Because my current ISP did not allow VPN connections.

Comment: @Muhamamd: I am not sure what you mean, as you can connect to USA servers with both of them. I live in the UK, and I have used FreeVPN to view Hulu in the US, in the past, but if your ISP blocks common VPNs, I guess you would have to find a private one, as I cannot see how they would block them all.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to remove DRM protection, but as far as I'm aware this is a US-based site, so we probably ought not to talk about them here, lest we attract the attention of the content cartels.

However, you may consider search terms like "fair use..."

Comment: "FairUse4WM" is not an option for me, because I'm not inside USA and I cannot play the movie. (Although I LEGALLY purchased the movie) FairUse4WM require to have valid license.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I think you want to stream the movie to your computer? If so, try a proxy that is inside the United States.

A quick google search gave me [this](http://www.usaproxy.org/). I checked it, and it is inside the USA.